# How to set a structs "name" value of type &'static str with a variable

Tags: rust

I just started learning rust the other day (so this is my first project in the language). I am trying to create a simple game and I want to have the player input their name and use it here is the player struct:

```
struct Player {
    health: i32,
    damage: i32,
    sprite: &'static str,
    name: &'static str,
    gold: i32,
}
```

and then in my main I call a function that simple returns a player inputted string:

```
fn main() 
{
    let player_name = ask_something("what is your name?");
    let player = Player {health: 10, damage: 3, sprite: &player_name.as_str(), name: "player", gold: 0};
}
```

But that gives me this error:

```
`player_name` does not live long enough
argument requires that `player_name` is borrowed for `'static`
```

So my question is how would I do this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an `&'static str` from a value you compute at runtime (including a value you get from user input). You'll have to add a lifetime parameter to your struct:

```rust
struct Player<'a> {
    health: i32,
    damage: i32,
    sprite: &'a str,
    name: &'a str,
    gold: i32,
}
```

Or you can use an owning type like `String` or `Box<str>` instead.

Comment: Is there any reason to ever use `Box<str>` over `String`?

Comment: Thank you! I tried to do something like that but my syntax knowledge of the language almost zero

Comment: @isaactfa `Box<str>` has a smaller size (pointer + length vs pointer + length + capacity). The only reason to use `Box<str>` is when you want to save the 4 bytes AND you won't need to modify the string within.

Comment: *Technically* you can get a `&'static str` from a value you compute at runtime (e.g. `Box::leak(string.into_boxed_str())`), but obviously that creates a memory leak and is not the right solution. `String`/`Box<str>` are both good suggestions and depending on your use case I might also suggest `Rc<str>` or some sort of string interning crate.

Comment: @PitaJ Technically you can change the string inside, e.g. `make_ascii_uppercase()`.